# How can I use Apple symbols on my website?

Tags: html, fonts, symbols

I've got to implement Apple symbols on my website. I've got the whole package installed:

```
AppleSymbols.woff
AppleSymbols.ttr
AppleSymbols.svg
AppleSymbols.eot
```

and:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'AppleSymbols';
    src: url('AppleSymbols.eot?') format('eot'), 
         url('AppleSymbols.woff') format('woff'), 
         url('AppleSymbols.ttf')  format('truetype'),
         url('AppleSymbols.svg#AppleSymbols') format('svg');
}
```

The problem is, how can I use this on my website?

Comment: Verify licensing before embedding a font. This font appears to be owned by Apple and has specific licensing. See http://oleb.net/blog/2009/10/apple-symbols-font-repository-for-iphone-icons/

Answer (score 0):

Now that you've linked the fonts, all you need to do is

```
p{
    font-family: 'AppleSymbols';
}
```

Or on whatever element you want to use that font.

If you want to see all the characters in that font, you can install it locally and [open it with FontBook (Mac)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/34241/view-all-a-fonts-characters-app) or open it with Windows Character Map. They'll show you the unicode character for whichever icon/character you'd like to use. Take that unicode character, and [convert it to an HTML entity.](http://unicode.online-toolz.com/tools/unicode-html-entities-convertor.php)

You should also keep in mind that you probably don't have license rights to use AppleSymbols. I like to avoid licensing issues by using TypeKit or Google fonts for client work. For symbol fonts, there are several great open license ones, like [Zurb Foundation Icons](http://foundation.zurb.com/icon-fonts.html).

Keep in mind the limitations of browsers when using @font-face, and include fall backs, like text labels if these icons are major elements of your UI. Also keep in mind screen reader/accessibility issues when using icons.

Answer (score 0):

&#8984; is the coded reference for the symbol you are looking for.

&#8984; = ⌘

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use svg as img on your site

```
<img src="AppleSymbols.svg" alt="Apple">
```

Comment: Sorry i don't get it.. I'm completely new in this... i added the code as you advise and what i see is only a image which the browser can't read. is there any symbols or code i need to use?

Comment: I think I misunderstood your question. Are you looking to display the Apple logo on your page or you want to display Apple logo as a character?

Comment: Hi Thanks for the quick answer
I have a font "Apple Symbol" that i need to use in my website.
There are a set of symbols. What i found is this http://www.ntg.nl/maps/30/09.pdf

Comment: Ahh my bad I thought you want to use svg as an image. Read here to use font in your website http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp

Comment: I think each symbol is assigned to a different key so you'll have to guess which key gives which symbol. Then you can define this in your css body { font-family: AppleSymbols; }

Comment: Yes that make sense but i can't find this code - symbols anywhere..? I have been looking everywhere for this Key - symbol.. Any idea?

Comment: That's quite hard to look for. You should try with a few keys first. Say A, B, C and see what they give. Also, why don't you insert those symbols as img instead of characters?

Comment: i tried no one is working well i need to use the bootstrap icone instead. If you will find any new idea please let me know
Thank you for the effort enyway!!